# Network share not accessible after adding new domain controller

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, network-shares, active-directory

I've got a bit of a weird one. Several users are connecting to our internal network shares from PCs that are not joined to our active directory domain. This has worked fine up until now when they are suddenly just getting the "\xx.xx.xx.xx is not accessible" error.

The only thing I can think of that has changed since this started is I added a read-only domain controller to the domain, although I can't see why this would cause connectivity issues.

Does anyone have any suggestions for diagnosing this?

Comment: Just to confirm, I've now demoted the read-only domain controller and access has now been restored, but why would this have happened?

Comment: You could check if there is any related Event log from both SMB sever and SMB client in Event viewer. **Event viewer**--> **Application and Services Logs**--> **Microsoft**--> **Windows**--> **SMBClient** or **SMB server**.